# String giving null in setdata method

Tags: android

I have a function which implements `Json` so in that function I am setting total likes of a video in a string data type.

```
        like_count = jo.getString("totallikes");

            setdata3(like_count);
```

The `setdata3` method is shown below. I put total likes in the `total_like` string , but I receive null in `likess` string.

```
    public void setdata3(String total_like){

    likess =  total_like;
        }


public String getdata3(){


    return likess ;
}
```

I am calling `getdata3` in `onCreate`.

Comment: @Koorosh any idea?

Comment: When do you set the data ?

Comment: i am setting the data in the function which implements json.

Comment: does any other code is executed between setdata3 and getdata3 that can influence likess?

Comment: i don't think so i am getting the total_like count but getting null in likess in the setter method on debugging

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling getdata3 in onCreate has the setdata3 already set the value or are you too early so getting null at that point in the object's life cycle.

Comment: in the setter method itself i am getting null in the String likess tho i am getting the likes count in the String total_like.